# Docker build error while building a kafka-connect 5.5.0 docker image

Tags: docker, confluent-platform

Getting this error while building a custom docker image for kafka-connect:5.5.0.
I do have "apt-get update" in necessary locations. Anyone has a clue on how to resolve this?

> W: Duplicate sources.list entry
> https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/staging-confluent-packages-5.5.0/deb/5.5/
> stable/main amd64 Packages
> (/var/lib/apt/lists/s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com_staging-confluent-packages-5.5.0_deb_5.5_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz)
> W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

Comment: Are you building `FROM confluentinc/cp-connect-base:5.5.0`?

Comment: I am using this: [link](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/tree/5.5.0-rc200418032830/kafka-connect) repo.

Comment: That image is already built and available in DockerHub. Can you not docker pull the version I listed?

Comment: I am adding some more connectors to this image as my architecture is on-prem and locked out of the internet.

Comment: "Locked out of the internet"... Then `apt-get update` will not work... Confluent uses Amazon S3 for their packages, as listed in the error

Comment: Should have phrased it better. The machine where I am making the custom image has the internet. I transfer my docker images to the on-prem machine and use helm to deploy them. So because I can't configure my running kafka-connect container due to this restriction, I have to make changes in the image source.

Comment: So, if that machine has access to the internet, still unclear why you cannot make a blank Dockerfile with the line from my first comment, then add your own details into that image?

Comment: Yes, I should have used the pre-built image and added libraries on top of it rather configuring the original image. I went this way around now and it seems to be getting working soon. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I should have approached installing any new packages on top of the pre-built image rather than adding them inside the original image.
My docker file to install influxDB connectors in Kafka-Connect ended up looking like this.

```
ARG DOCKER_TAG=5.5.0
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:${DOCKER_TAG}
ENV COMPONENT=kafka-connect
USER root
RUN echo "===> Installing InfluxDB Connectors"
RUN confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-influxdb:latest --no-prompt \
    && echo "===> Cleaning up ..."  \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

And Influx connectors are now working in my production.